# Unable to parse XML object

Tags: node.js, arrays, object, node-red

(I don't use Node-Red for a long time but I have some knowledge of Javascript syntax using NodeJS and client side libraries like jQuery.)

I can read my file and parse it correctly. Data object is valid (see green arrow) and syntax to access structured object is good.

```
let arr = msg.payload
    .VariablesExchangeFile
    .DDTSource[0]
    .structure[0]
    .variables;

return arr;
```

But My **`arr` variable is empty** (see red arrow) !!! And I don't understand why.

[image: details of problem]

I copied the path to the child object from debug Window, and it's the same path (see yellow shapes) : `payload.VariablesExchangeFile.DDTSource[0].structure[0].variables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is not empty, the problem is that you are not returning a `msg` object from the function node.

You are returning the array object which does not have a `payload` field and you have the debug node set to only print out the `msg.payload` field.

Change the function node as follows:

```
let msg.payload = msg.payload
    .VariablesExchangeFile
    .DDTSource[0]
    .structure[0]
    .variables;

return msg;
```